# How can I reset the jsdom instance when using vitest in order to test a History-based router?

Tags: javascript, svelte, jsdom, testing-library, vitest

I'd like to do some integration testing of my `svelte` + `page.js`-based router using `vitest`, but I'm running into an issue where the `jsdom` instance only updates correctly once per test file.

In the following setup, either test will pass when run with `.only` or if I split each test into its own file. But when they run in sequence, the second one will always fail. Inspecting the DOM with `screen.debug()` reveals that it's empty, and calls to `act` or `tick` don't seem to do anything.

I suspect it has something to do with how `jsdom` is interacting with the History API, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

**Root.svelte**

```
<script>
  import page from 'page'

  import SignIn from './SignIn/SignIn.svelte'
  import Upload from './Upload/Upload.svelte'
  import { authenticationToken } from './Root.stores.js'

  let currentPage

  page('/', () => {
    page.redirect('/sign-in')
  })

  page('/sign-in', () => {
    currentPage = SignIn
  })

  page('/upload', () => {
    if ($authenticationToken === null) {
      return page.redirect('/sign-in')
    }

    currentPage = Upload
  })

  page.start()
</script>

<svelte:component this={ currentPage } />
```

**Root.svelte.test.js**

```
import page from 'page'
import Root from './Root.svelte'
import { authenticationToken } from './Root.stores.js'

it('redirects to sign in when not authenticated', async () => {
  vi.spyOn(page, 'redirect')
  authenticationToken.set(null)

  const { act } = setupComponent(Root)
  await act(() => page('/upload'))

  expect(page.redirect).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/sign-in')
})

it('displays the upload screen when authenticated', async () => {
  authenticationToken.set('token')

  const { act } = setupComponent(Root)
  await act(() => page('/upload'))

  expect(document.getElementById('upload')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

**Other Research**

The issue is similar to [this one](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5987#issue-314368230) in the `jest` project. In that issue, the [recommendation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5987#issuecomment-381394023) was to call `jsdom.reconfigure()` in a `beforeEach` block, but I don't know how to get a hold of the `jsdom` instance in `vitest` in order to try that.

Any ideas or alternative approaches welcome, thanks!

Comment: I know this was a little while ago but I would love to know if you ever made any progress? I have a similar / related question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75795059/2883500 ... I think if I could find a way to reset JSDOM window in between tests without having to move to separate files I'd be good to go.

Comment: @pooley1994 I couldn't find a solution so I am now using E2E tests for routing. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.3.0, Vitest exposes a `jsdom` global variable, so it should be possible to call

```
jsdom.reconfigure(/* ... */)
```

See also https://vitest.dev/config/#environment (scroll to the bottom of the section)